# How can I make this little javascript work with 2 textarea elements without killing the CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, textarea, highlighting

The basics:

I'm styling a textarea with CSS, and using javascript to highlight the textarea when the user clicks inside.

This works fine with one textarea, but when I try to make more (by changing the javascript from `.getElementById` to `.getElementsByClassName` and updating the tags accordingly) I mess something up and lose all of the CSS.

How can I make this work with two textareas?

Cheers and thanks for your help!

.html page:

```
<textarea name="styled-textarea" id="styled" ; this.onfocus=null; setbg('#e5fff3')">All      this nice stuff goes inside here | http://www.website.com</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox = document.getElementById("styled");
    textBox.onfocus = function() {
    textBox.select();

    // Work around Chrome's little problem
    textBox.onmouseup = function() {
        // Prevent further mouseup intervention
        textBox.onmouseup = null;
        return false;
    };
};
</script>

All this nice stuff goes inside here.
<textarea name="styled-textarea" id="styled" ; this.onfocus=null; setbg('#e5fff3')">All     this nice stuff goes inside here | http://www.website.com</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
textarea#styled {
width: 60%;
font-size: 24px;
border: 3px solid #cccccc;
padding: 5px;
font-family:'Arial', sans-serif
}
```

Comment: Cut and paste error with your textarea code? Definitely some invalid stuff in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to edit mrtsherman's answer, but my suggestion was rejected, so I'll just add a new answer. The code below fixes his.

Switching from `.getElementById` to `.getElementsByClassName` requires three things:

1. Changing `id` to `class` on both your `textarea` elements.
2. Updating your CSS from `textarea#styled` to `textarea.styled`.
3. Use `.getElementsByClassName` instead of `.getElementById` (note, it returns an array of elements, not one).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/WnJar/

Script:

```
var textBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("styled");

for (var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++) {

    var textBox = textBoxes[i];

    textBox.onfocus = function() {

        this.select();

        // Work around Chrome's little problem
        this.onmouseup = function() {

            // Prevent further mouseup intervention
            this.onmouseup = null;
            return false;

        };

    };

};
```

Comment: Voila! I really appreciate your help, ThinkingStiff. This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't have 2 elements on the same page with the same ID. If you want to apply the same style to 2 different elements on the same page, use class="styled" instead of id="styled". An id should uniquely **id**entify a single element in the HTML.

Secondly, I wouldn't use document.getElementById or any kind of raw javascript to do this. You're better off using a library like jQuery to handle things like this.

```
textarea.unstyled {
    background-color: #e5fff3;
} 

textarea.styled {
    width: 60%;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 3px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family:'Arial', sans-serif
} 

<textarea name="styled-textarea1" id="styled-textarea1" class="unstyled">
    Content
</textarea>
<textarea name="styled-textarea2" id="styled-textarea2" class="unstyled">
    Content
</textarea>
```

$('textarea').focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass('styled');
});

[Take a look at the jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Comment: Thank You! I'm experimenting with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style elements then you don't need javascript for this at all. Use the :focus pseudoselector to do it.

```
textarea:focus { color: blue; }
```

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/EZaVA/3

```
var textBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("styled");

for (var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++) {
    var textBox = textBoxes[i];
    textBox.onfocus = function() {
        this.select();

        // Work around Chrome's little problem
        this.onmouseup = function() {
            // Prevent further mouseup intervention
            this.onmouseup = null;
            return false;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I want the text highlighted so it's ready to copy, though.

Comment: k, updated my answer. For future reference I wouldn't use the phrase 'styling a textbox' because it implies you are using css. In reality you are performing selections via javascript.

Comment: For some reason, only one textarea will respond. Maybe it's a browser issue. Thank You again for your help. I'll work on this tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, I messed it up while cleaning up the code. Updated my answer. You have to use 'this' inside the anonymous function to reference the current element.